# Can I install multi Parallels on my Mac?

Tags: parallels

Can I install multi Parallels on my Mac?

I installed a [Parallels](https://www.parallels.com) with Windows in my Mac, it works fine, but I want to install one more that with Linux System.

How can I realize it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create and run as many different virtual machines as you want in a single installation of Parallels Desktop. You don't need to install multiple copies, just create multiple VMs.

Comment: Can you explain more?